# Calling partial view through Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, model-view-controller, partial-views

I am calling partial view through Ajax but it gives result undefined.

My controller is:

```
[HttpGet]
     public  ActionResult CallPartial()
  {
       if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
       {              
          return PartialView("~/Views/Partial1");
       }
       else
       {
          return View();
       }
    }
```

and my view is:

```
 <div id="divpartial">hello
 <button id="btn" onclick="callpartial()">Click</button>

 </div>


 <script type="text/javascript" >
   $(function callpartial() {
      $.ajax({
           url: '~/Controllers/Home/CallPartial',

          contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
         type: 'Get',
          dataType: 'html',
         success: function (status) {$("#divpartial").html("Welcome to partial view"); },
          error: function (status) {
              alert(status.Value);
          }
                               alert("Request Fails");
    });

});
```

and finaly my partial view is:

```
<body>
<div>hello this partial</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your route is bad, typically in MVC you dont have the word 'Controllers' in your route.  Try this:

```
url: '@Url.Action("CallPartial", "Home")',
```

Comment: Happy to help!  So your code is not going into the Request.IsAjaxRequest() block?

Comment: No I think it was browser issue. now its working fine. Thank you once again.